# Multiple Fully loose mapping SolrNet Init

Tags: c#, vb.net, solr, containers, solrnet

I need to use multiple solr core on the same project, i'm using SolrNet and default Startup.Init that register the instance on CurrentServiceLocator, i'm wondering how to register multiple loose mapping core in the following way.

```
    Dim solrurl As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SolrServer1")
    Startup.Init(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(solrurl)

    Dim solrurl2 As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SolrServer2")
    Startup.Init(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(solrurl2)
```

This cause collision on key on with following error:

Key 'SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection.System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object].SolrNet.Impl.SolrConnection' already registered in container